# Complex number calculation (to the third power)

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a question that asks me to calculate $Z_1^3$ knowing that $Z_1 = 5 + 5i$

So, first I calculate by using the most straight-forward method which is $Z_1\cdot Z_1\cdot Z_1$ by using the formula $Z_1\cdot Z_2 = (a_1a_2-b_1b_2)+(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)i$

The answer is $-250+250i$ (The same as the answer on the answer key and provided by the calculator)

However, I then tried to calculate by using De Moivre's formula by converting this complex number to polar coordinates:

- $Z_1 = p\operatorname{cis}\theta$
- $p = \sqrt{5^2+5^2} = \sqrt{50} $
- $\theta = \arctan(5/5) = 45^\circ$
- $Z_1 = \sqrt{50}\operatorname{cis}45$

According to the De Movire's formula, $Z^n = p^ncis(n*\theta)$, therefore:

- $Z_1 = \sqrt{50}^3\operatorname{cis}135^\circ$

However, there is no way this can equal to $-250+250i$, since $ \sqrt{50}^3$ is surely not a whole number.

Then I am not sure where I did wrong? I also followed the example in the book where they do the same to calculate $(1+i)^{10}$.

Comment: Can you evaluate $cis 135 ^ \circ$? __Hint:__ The product of 2 non-integers could also be an integer.

Comment: Did you mean $p=\sqrt{50}$?

Comment: @CalvinLin I know cis135 = cos(135) + sin(135) = 0

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes sorry, a typo. I just changed! Thank you for noticing that

Comment: and what is $\cos(135^o)$?

Comment: FYI $cis \theta \neq 0 $ for all $\theta$, so you should recheck your working.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong. The distance of $-250+250i$ from the origin is still $\sqrt{50}^3=2\sqrt2\cdot125$.

Comment: Other typos:   $Z_1=\sqrt{50}\dots$, $Z_1^{\color{red}3}=\dots$

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, i realize the mistake. I was assuming since $\sqrt{12500}$ isn't a whole number, then the result couldn't be a whole number. Apparently, after multiplying it by $cos135$, it is!

Comment: Great, can you type up your answer to this question? Thanks.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes I did! Thank you for helping!

Comment: $\sqrt{50}^3$ is not a whole number but neither are $\sin 135$ or $\cos 135$.  WHat matters is $\sqrt{50}^3*\sin 135$ and $$\sqrt{50}^2 \cos 135$ are whole numbers which they surely are.

Comment: Note:  You *BEGAN* with $\sqrt{50}cis 45$.  $\sqrt{50}$ is just as much a whole number or not as $\sqrt{50}^3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that I was assuming since $\sqrt{125000}$ isn't a whole number, then the result couldn't be a whole number. However, apparently, after multiplying it by $cos135$ it is!

So the answer should be

- $cis135 = cos135+sin135$
- $Re(Z_1) = pcos\theta = \sqrt{125000}cos135 = -250$
- $Im(Z_1) = psin\theta = \sqrt{125000}sin153 = 250$
- $Z_1 = -250 + 250i$

Thank you for helping me on this!